# How to disable `accesskey` when the element is hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hidden, access-keys

Please see the below code:

```js
$('div').click(function(){
   alert("Shortcut worked although element was hidden!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div hidden accesskey="1">
    Some things...
</div>

<p>
  Focus on me and then 
  </br>
  <b>press [Alt + 1] please!</b>
</p>
```

How can I to disable `accesskey` when the element get hide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to disable the `accesskey`, you just need to `add / remove` that as per you need

```
if(!$('div').is(":visible"))
{
   $('div').removeAttr('accesskey');
}
else
{
   $('div').attr('accesskey', '1');
}
```

```js
if(!$('div').is(":visible"))
{
  $('div').removeAttr('accesskey');
}
else
{
  $('div').attr('accesskey', '1');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div hidden accesskey="1">
    Some things...
</div>

<p>
  Focus on me and then 
  </br>
  <b>press [Alt + 1] please!</b>
</p>
```

Comment: Or maybe store the previous value using `.data()` so that you can restore that value rather than hardcoding the `'1'`.

Comment: Or if you're refreshing the page, you can use `localStorage` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the `div` is `hidden` in the `click` event:

```
$('div').click(function(event) {

  if (!$(this).is(':hidden')) {
    alert("Shortcut worked although element was hidden!");
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/89b2jtmw/1/